# exclude nodes from xpath query

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Here's some code I am currently using. Where I need help are `$bn_name_search` and `$bn_id_search`

```
$xpath_base='/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item[';
for ($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
    $curr_item_base=$xpath_base.$i.']';
    $bn_name_search=$curr_item_base.'/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode/Name/text()';
    $bn_id_search=$curr_item_base.'/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode/BrowseNodeId/text()';
    $bn_names=$parsed->xpath($bn_name_search);
    $bn_ids=$parsed->xpath($bn_id_search);
  }
```

This gives me all the browsnode names and all the broswnode ids. What I'd like to do now is find only the browsenode names "`BrowseNode/Name/`" that are not "All Products" and only browsnode ids "`BrowseNode/BrowseNodeId/`" share a "`BrowseNode/`" with a name that is not "All Products" I don't have to test for the existance of `BrowseNode/Name`. It won't be blank if there is an ID. If I can put two negative expressions it would be even better. I would omit those whose names are "All Products" and those whose names are "Departments"

**EDIT:**
Here's a block of the XML: Where it says "`&lt;Name&gt;Departments&lt;/Name&gt;`", I'd like to exclude that name and it's ID. If I have a similare one that says "`&lt;Name&gt;All Products&lt;/Name&gt;`" I'd also like to exclude that name and it's ID. (by ID, I mean `&lt;BrowseNodeId&gt;`)

```
<BrowseNodes>
  <BrowseNode>
    <BrowseNodeId>2346727011</BrowseNodeId>
    <Name>Casual</Name>
    <Ancestors>
      <BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNodeId>1045024</BrowseNodeId>
        <Name>Dresses</Name>
        <Ancestors>
          <BrowseNode>
            <BrowseNodeId>1040660</BrowseNodeId>
            <Name>Women</Name>
            <Ancestors>
              <BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNodeId>1036682</BrowseNodeId>
                <Name>Departments</Name>
                <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                <Ancestors>
                  <BrowseNode>
                    <BrowseNodeId>1036592</BrowseNodeId>
                    <Name>Clothing &amp; Accessories</Name>
                  </BrowseNode>
                </Ancestors>
              </BrowseNode>
            </Ancestors>
          </BrowseNode>
        </Ancestors>
      </BrowseNode>
    </Ancestors>
  </BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I'll try one or two of them out when I get to work in the A.M.

Comment: Just for future reference, if you want a fast answer it's best to post as much info as as you can, and an input/output if possible.

Comment: Any number of the answers below MIGHT have worked. I had an error in my test code, so NOTHING was working. Finally, the simplest answer (in my eyes) is what worked for me. Thanks again to everyone who offered an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you go:

```
$nodes = $parsed->xpath("//BrowseNode[Name!='Departments' and Name!='All Products']");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo "Id: {$node->BrowseNodeId}, name: {$node->Name}\n";
}
```

Comment: I think you nailed it! It took me a while because I had another logic error in my testing code, but here's my actual strings: `"/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode[Name!='Departments' and Name!='All Products']/Name/text()";` and `"/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode[Name!='Departments' and Name!='All Products']/BrowseNodeId/text()"`

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing how your xml is structured, I came up with xpath for what I thought you were trying to do. I also wasn't too sure about the `BrowseNodeId` that "share" a browsenode name, I assumed this meant to give the `BrowseNodeId`s for all `BrowseNode`s that had the name set to this.

I combined your xpath outside of the php to visualize it better:

```
/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item[i]/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode/Name/text()
/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item[i]/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode/
```

Combined solution:

```
/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item[i]/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode/Name[text()!='All Products']/text()
/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item[i]/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode[Name/text()!='All Departments']/BrowseNodeId/text()
```

Php solution:

```
$xpath_base='/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item[';
for ($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++)
  {
    $curr_item_base=$xpath_base.$i.']';
    $bn_name_search=$curr_item_base.'/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode/Name[text()!='All Products']';
    $bn_id_search=$curr_item_base.'/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode[Name/text()!='All Departments']/BrowseNodeId/text()';
    $bn_names=$parsed->xpath($bn_name_search);
    $bn_ids=$parsed->xpath($bn_id_search);
  }
```

**Updated**
To combine the xpath, you could use concatenate `|` :

```
/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item[i]/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode[Name/text()!=\'Departments\' and Name/text()!=\'All Products\']/BrowseNodeId/text() | 
/ItemSearchResponse/Items/Item[i]/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode/Name[text()!=\'All Products\' and text()!=\'Departments\']
```

php:
**(Updated)**

```
$bn_combined_search=$curr_item_base.'/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode[Name/text()!=\'Departments\' and Name/text()!=\'All Products\']/BrowseNodeId/text() |'.$curr_item_base.'/BrowseNodes//BrowseNode/Name[text()!=\'All Products\' and text()!=\'Departments\']';
```

If I made a wrong assumption, post some of your xml and elaborate on the solution you're looking for. Hope this helps!

Comment: Please see my question. I'm updating it with a snippet from the XML.

Comment: Are you expecting the names/ids of Casual/dresses/woman/clothing and accessories? Or are child elements of Departments/All Products to also be left from the query?

Answer (score 2):

**Use**:

```
//BrowseNode
      [not(contains('|Departments|All Products|',
                    concat('|', Name, '|')
                    )
          )
      ]/Name
```

This expression selects any `Name` elements that is a child of a `BrowseNode` element and whose string value isn't one of the strings `"Departments"` or `"All Products"`.

**Use**:

```
//BrowseNode
      [not(contains('|Departments|All Products|',
                    concat('|', Name, '|')
                    )
          )
      ]
       /BrowseNodeId
```

This selects any `BrowseNodeId` element that is a child of a `BrowseNode` element and that has a `Name` sibling whose string value isn't one of the strings `"Departments"` or `"All Products"`.

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "//BrowseNode
      [not(contains('|Departments|All Products|',
                    concat('|', Name, '|')
                    )
          )
      ]/Name
      "/>
=================

  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "//BrowseNode
      [not(contains('|Departments|All Products|',
                    concat('|', Name, '|')
                    )
          )
      ]
       /BrowseNodeId
      "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<BrowseNodes>
    <BrowseNode>
        <BrowseNodeId>2346727011</BrowseNodeId>
        <Name>Casual</Name>
        <Ancestors>
            <BrowseNode>
                <BrowseNodeId>1045024</BrowseNodeId>
                <Name>Dresses</Name>
                <Ancestors>
                    <BrowseNode>
                        <BrowseNodeId>1040660</BrowseNodeId>
                        <Name>Women</Name>
                        <Ancestors>
                            <BrowseNode>
                                <BrowseNodeId>1036682</BrowseNodeId>
                                <Name>Departments</Name>
                                <IsCategoryRoot>1</IsCategoryRoot>
                                <Ancestors>
                                    <BrowseNode>
                                        <BrowseNodeId>1036592</BrowseNodeId>
                                        <Name>Clothing &amp; Accessories</Name>
                                    </BrowseNode>
                                </Ancestors>
                            </BrowseNode>
                        </Ancestors>
                    </BrowseNode>
                </Ancestors>
            </BrowseNode>
        </Ancestors>
    </BrowseNode>
</BrowseNodes>
```

**the two XPath expressions are evaluated and their results (separated by the `"========"` string are copied to the output**.

We can thus verify from the result of the transformation that exactly the wanted `Name` and `BrowseNodeId` elements are selected:

```
<Name>Casual</Name>
<Name>Dresses</Name>
<Name>Women</Name>
<Name>Clothing &amp; Accessories</Name>
=================

<BrowseNodeId>2346727011</BrowseNodeId>
<BrowseNodeId>1045024</BrowseNodeId>
<BrowseNodeId>1040660</BrowseNodeId>
<BrowseNodeId>1036592</BrowseNodeId>
```